# are the functions also $1-1$ and surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Knowing that $f: X \to Y \text{ and } g:Y \to Z$ are $1-1$ and surjective,are then also $f^{-1}: Y \to X$ and $g \circ f:X \to Z$ $1-1$ and surjective or just $1-1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

1) $f^{-1}$ is surjective and 1-1, because for every $x \in X   \ \ f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ and if $f^{-1}(a) = f^{-1}(b)$ then $a = f(f^{-1}(a)) = f(f^{-1}(b)) = b$

2) $g \circ f $ is surjective and $1-1$, because if $g \circ f (a) = g \circ f (b)  $ then $f(a) = f(b) $ and so $a = b$. Moreover for every $z \in Z $,  let $b \in Y $ be such that $g(b) = z $ and $a \in X $ such that $f(a) = b $. Then $g \circ f (a) = z$

Comment: Bijective means $1-1$ and surjective, so your first sentence is redundant. I assume you meant "surjective and $1-1$."

Comment: To go from the relation $ f^{-1} (a)= f^{-1} (b) $ to the relation $a=f (f^{-1}(a))= f (f^{-1}(b))=b$ don't we have to know that $f^{-1}$ is invertible?

Comment: yes, infact $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$